# Queue like Subject in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I'm looking for a Subject (or something similar) that can:

1. Could receive items and hold them in a queue or buffer if there are no subscribers
2. Once we have a subscriber all items are consumed and never emitted again
3. I can subscribe/unsubscribe to/from Subject

`BehaviorSubject` almost would do the job, but it retains last observed item.

**UPDATE**

Based on accepted answer I worked out similar solution for single observed item. Also added unsubscription part to avoid memory leaks.

```
class LastEventObservable private constructor(
        private val onSubscribe: OnSubscribe<Any>,
        private val state: State
) : Observable<Any>(onSubscribe) {

    fun emit(value: Any) {
        if (state.subscriber.hasObservers()) {
            state.subscriber.onNext(value)
        } else {
            state.lastItem = value
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): LastEventObservable {
            val state = State()

            val onSubscribe = OnSubscribe<Any> { subscriber ->
                just(state.lastItem)
                        .filter { it != null }
                        .doOnNext { subscriber.onNext(it) }
                        .doOnCompleted { state.lastItem = null }
                        .subscribe()

                val subscription = state.subscriber.subscribe(subscriber)

                subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create { subscription.unsubscribe() })
            }

            return LastEventObservable(onSubscribe, state)
        }
    }

    private class State {
        var lastItem: Any? = null
        val subscriber = PublishSubject.create<Any>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "Once we have a subscriber all items are consumed and never emitted again" - if you have something like: yourSource.take(1).subscribe(), should that wipe out all the items from yourSource?

Comment: No, that should consume only that item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I achieve the expected result creating a customized Observable that wraps a publish subject and handles emission cache if there's no subscribers attached. Check it out.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        MyCustomObservable myCustomObservable = new MyCustomObservable();

        myCustomObservable.emit("1");
        myCustomObservable.emit("2");
        myCustomObservable.emit("3");

        Subscription subscription = myCustomObservable.subscribe(System.out::println);

        myCustomObservable.emit("4");
        myCustomObservable.emit("5");

        subscription.unsubscribe();

        myCustomObservable.emit("6");
        myCustomObservable.emit("7");
        myCustomObservable.emit("8");

        myCustomObservable.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}

class MyCustomObservable extends Observable<String> {
    private static PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    private static List<String> valuesCache = new ArrayList<>();

    protected MyCustomObservable() {
        super(subscriber -> {
            Observable.from(valuesCache)
                    .doOnNext(subscriber::onNext)
                    .doOnCompleted(valuesCache::clear)
                    .subscribe();

            publishSubject.subscribe(subscriber);
        });
    }

    public void emit(String value) {
        if (publishSubject.hasObservers()) {
            publishSubject.onNext(value);
        } else {
            valuesCache.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that it helps!

Best Regards.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Wasn't too fond of those static variables though :)

Comment: Me neither @MartynasJurkus . How can we improve this solution?

Comment: See my updated question. Although my code is in Kotlin.

Comment: Awesome! I love Koltin. Your final solution is much prettier than my initial one.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to wait for a single subscriber, use `UnicastSubject` but note that if you unsubscribe in the middle, all subsequent queued items will be lost.

Edit:

> Once we have **a** subscriber all items are consumed and never emitted again

For multiple subscribers, use `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: There should be possibility to have multiple subscribers.

Comment: @MartynasJurkus You can use `UnicastSubject` with `.publish().autoConnect()` but you can't "cache" items between 1st unsubscribe and 2nd subscribe.
But there's library https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions which has `UnicastWorkerSubject` that allows that (but still with 1 subscriber at once) or `DispatchWorkSubject` that allows many subscribers. Unfortunately you can't specify buffer size because in `create()` method you can pass `capacityHint` which isn't a specify capacity size. It's just a hint because of the implementation of `SpscLinkedArrayQueue` and `SpmcLinkedArrayQueue`

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, my requirements were:

- Should support replay of values when no Observer subscribed
- Should allow only one Observer subscribed at a time
- Should allow another Observer to subscribe when first Observer is disposed

I've implemented it as [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay) but the implementation for Subject would be similar:

```
public final class CacheRelay<T> extends Relay<T> {

    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final PublishRelay<T> relay = PublishRelay.create();

    private CacheRelay() {
    }

    public static <T> CacheRelay<T> create() {
        return new CacheRelay<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T value) {
        if (relay.hasObservers()) {
            relay.accept(value);
        } else {
            queue.add(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return relay.hasObservers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
        if (hasObservers()) {
            EmptyDisposable.error(new IllegalStateException("Only a single observer at a time allowed."), observer);
        } else {
            for (T element; (element = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
                observer.onNext(element);
            }
            relay.subscribeActual(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Look at this [Gist for more](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fxsveda%2F8c556516079fde97d04b4b7e14a18463&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGDCLX8W_iB9OSsrlZs2F2I3bQ-Hg)**

Comment: I created a library that was inspired by this post: https://github.com/vrendina/RxQueue

Comment: How to move the work to background thread? All the operations in the queue are executed in the main thread.