# RXJava sequential execution of http requests

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a method that accepts a URL. This method will be called multiple times (not a fixed number).

I create an observable for each URL:

```
Observable.create(Action1<Emitter<String>> {

    // synchronous call
    val response: String? = client.doPost(localUrl, json, null)
    it.onNext(response)

}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe({
            // DO STUFF
        })
```

I must call these urls in the same sequence that i got them (e.g. call URL number 1 and get the result, then go for URL number 2 and so on)

Any suggestions if/how can this be done using RXJava?

Comment: have you taken a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728555/queue-like-subject-in-rxjava

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. Will give it a try and update